# how to implement a search in an array containing book names in c

Tags: c, search, struct, char

i have this array of structs

```
struct BookInfo
{
    char title[50];
    int numAuthors;
    char authors[50][50];
    int year;
    int checkedout;
};

struct BookInfo library[500];
```

and i am trying to figure out how to implement a search where a user can type a word and the function will print the whole name of that book 
for example in char title two books are

```
a rose for emily
war of the worlds
```

if user types worlds the function will print

```
war of the worlds
```

how does one go about this ive seen the linear searches with ints but not with char data types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code.It uses `strstr()` to match the keyword with the titles in the list.For convenience to test the code,I have only the `title` field in `BookInfo` and I have limited the number of items in `library` to 5.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct BookInfo
{
    char title[50];
};

struct BookInfo library[5];

int main()
{
    int i,j=0;
    char keyword[50];

//Getting the titles of books from librarian

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter book no.%d ",i+1);
        gets(library[i].title);
    }
 // Search based on keyword

    printf("Enter the title keyword to search\n");
    gets(keyword);
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(strstr(library[i].title,keyword)==NULL)
            j++;

        else
            printf("Book to have the  word %s in title is %s\n",keyword,library[i].title);

    }
    if(j==0)
        printf("No book with given title/keyword");
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter book no.1 The importance of religion

Enter book no.2 Why sex sells

Enter book no.3 Origin of species

Enter book no.4 Are you obsessed with sex?

Enter book no.5 Why are programmers sexy

Enter the title keyword to search sex

Book to have the  word sex in title is Why sex sells

Book to have the  word sex in title is Are you obsessed with sex?

Book to have the  word sex in title is Why are programmers sexy
```

Comment: @Tatan1 I tried it too, and it works well,I am adding the output too.Wait.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways that you can implement it. But, to me, the best convenient way to implement this is to use of "Trie" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie. Use of trie can help you implement this in a very efficient way.